# How can I list Stack Overflow votes?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, voting, profile-page

How can I list Stack Overflow votes?

I clicked many plus (upvote) buttons. How can I get a list of those votes?

Comment: There is no plus button here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to your `profile` > Then click on `Votes` tab on right most side.

like mine https://stackoverflow.com/users/1160106/samiron-paul?tab=votes

Your one should be 
https://stackoverflow.com/users/1049667/zszen?tab=votes though it's not available to public

Comment: thx, now I find it. thx very much. LOL. little trouble.

Comment: thats great!! can i have a accept ? :)

Comment: why somebody give me -1 ? :'(

Comment: @zszen That was me - because you originally posted on stackoverflow, not meta. Not to mention without the tags & edits by gnat it was hard to decipher what the question was.

Comment: I can't post a new question. Is it because I post a idiot quest? Now I need help. :(